# Need Help for my Custom Page Template

Tags: wordpress

I'm very new to this PHP coding.. actually I'm not a programmer, but I need this help from anyone here...

Anyway, what I need help from you:

I have written a small snippet of Custom Page template, here it is:

```
------------------------------

<?php
/*
Template Name: MyCustomTemplate
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

------------------------------
```

Now I have installed a wordpress slider plugin "Nivo Slider"..

Now I'm not understanding how do I call this plugin into my custom template...

Iam trying to achive home page with a Slider and some ads in it.. eg: I need my home page like this: www.papayaclothing.com/shop/

So, could anyone please provide me a code to work that?

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow,i am not a php guy but i think you should check this plugin documentation, hopefully there you find a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code, make sure that slider you are trying to call is published:

```
<?php 

//valid for Nivo Slider version < 1.8
echo do_shortcode('[nivoslider slug="my-slider"]');

?>
```

Let me know if my answer was helpful.

Comment: hey hi,  Iam getting this Fatal Error:   

    Fatal error: Call to undefined function nivo_slider() in /home/john08/public_html/mydomainname.com/wp-content/themes/canvas/TheLegend.php on line 12

Comment: which version of Nivo Slider do you  use?

Comment: My Nivo Slider : Version 1.7.1

Comment: Please try following code:

<?php

echo do_shortcode('[nivoslider slug="my-slider"]');

?>

Comment: But one thing: In this NivoSlider plugin, I can see a column called 'ShortCode', but Iam thinking to use some other plugin like woothemes woo slider plugin v1.0.4  from here, you can get: http://rapidgator.net/file/36922600  , so how can I get a shortcodes for this wooslider plugin and how can i use this plugin now in my custom template..?

The main problem iam facing with nivoslider is, Iam unable to keep anchor texts for it..

Extremely sorry if iam troubling U...

thnx a lot! can u also make this new plugin work?

Comment: Hello bro,

Now iam able to see keep anchor links for NivoSlider plugin, but Iam facing 2 problems:

a) How can I increase or decrease of slider?
b) How can re-use more than 1 time this nivoslider plugin in my custom template?


do you think its possible to rectify above 2...?

Comment: Hi, I will try to help you. I would need more information for anchor texts, could you paste example how anchor texts should work?

a) How can I increase or decrease of slider?
>Are you trying to increase/decrease width or hight? This could be possible by editig Plugin Settings in Wordpress Admin. Other way is to write custom css settings for a plugin.you want to see the Nivo Slider. You could use NivoSlider as many times as you like in the template.

Comment: b) How can re-use more than 1 time this nivoslider plugin in my custom template.

> This should be possible by copy/paste <?php echo do_shortcode('[nivoslider slug="my-slider"]'); ?> in the place where
you like to use it. You may use many plugin calls in the template.

I will check woo slider later through the day and i will send you an answer about the plugin.

Comment: Here is a sample code that shows how to use Woo Slider:

<?php  echo do_shortcode("[wooslider id='6']"); ?>

You may find more information on [WooSlider site](http://www.woothemes.com/wooslider/)

Comment: Hello Bro,

sorry for late reply.. 

When I tried to use again this code:  


<div align="center">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[nivoslider slug="my-slider"]'); ?> 
</div>

this is NOT loading 2nd time, slider keeps showing as 'loading' but not displaying on my website..

Comment: Regarding WooSLider: this code: <?php echo do_shortcode("[wooslider id='6']"); ?>  NOT working for me, may I know how to find id?

I tried like this too: <div align="center">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wooslider slug="test-group"]'); ?>
</div> , BUT still its not displaying on my website..

and thnq vm for trying to help me out! :)